# Redux: Generic update action

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm working with Redux and my state is a normalized one with a lot of different models. Now I was wondering myself if it was better to have specific actions like:

```
{type: CHANGE_MODEL_NAME, modelId, name}
```

vs

```
{type: UPDATE_MODEL, modelId, {name}}
```

I did a bit of searching and I found this question:

[Is it ok to create generic redux update action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42116228/is-it-ok-to-create-generic-redux-update-action)

Now what I'm wondering is that no one is adressing the fact that having specific action types allow for different reducers to 'react' to an action in a cleaner way.

IE: I have a model that is copied from another model like so:

```
{
  name: 'foo',
  originalModel: id_0
}
```

It then becomes easier to react to specific actions in my reducer of copied models if I only want to react to the name change action.

Is it wrong for 2 reducers to react to the same actions? Is that why nobody adressed this issue in the original question?

Answer (score 2):

Having multiple slice reducers respond to the same actions is absolutely an intended use case for Redux.  I covered that background in my post [The Tao of Redux, Part 1 - Implementation and Intent](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/05/idiomatic-redux-tao-of-redux-part-1/).

As for your specific question: I think it's entirely valid to have an update action for normalized data that contains the item type name and the item ID.  In fact, I demonstrated this exact approach in my post [Practical Redux, Part 7: Form Change Handling, Data Editing, and Feature Reducers](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/practical-redux-part-7-forms-editing-reducers/).

Overall, Redux itself doesn't care what specific action types you have and how generic they are.  You are encouraged to define whatever actions are appropriate for your app, and what level of "abstraction" they represent.  It's very reasonable to make them a bit more generic - for example, I'd prefer `UPDATE_USER_ATTRIBUTES` instead of `SET_USER_FIRST_NAME` and `SET_USER_LAST_NAME`, but ultimately it's up to you.

Comment: Thank you, I will read those posts. One thing that I find harder with Redux is that all the examples are for webapp that are so simple you wouldn't even need Redux. When you grow to more complex and nested data with a lot of possible user actions it becomes less clear what is good practice and what isn't,

Comment: Yeah, for library docs it's always tough to trade off between "keep it simple so we can teach the principles of the library", vs "here's how this gets used in the real world".  That's why I've been writing both of my main blog post series, to help cover those "real-world" questions and usages.  Also, see the [Redux Architecture](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/redux-architecture.md) and [Redux Techniques](https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/redux-techniques.md) sections of my links list for more articles and examples.

Comment: I've skimmed your blog and I'm def gonna read it more thoroughly later, but I wanted to pick your brain on something. Let's say you want to create a model that can live by itself but you want to add the id of this model somewhere else at the same time. Where would you generate that id so that the second action (the one that adds the id) can retrieve the new id.

Comment: Generation of any random values should be done on the action creator side of things.  My "Practical Redux" series doesn't show creation examples yet - I'll hopefully get to that eventually. But, for examples of randomness, see [Roll the Dice: Random Numbers in Redux](https://daveceddia.com/random-numbers-in-redux/) and [Random in Redux](https://blog.ohlman.io/random-in-redux-b6b9932ad061).

Comment: My problem is more along the fact that another action that will follow needs the random value to be completed

Comment: Not sure what the issue is there.  If you need to dispatch multiple actions in a row, use a thunk.  Generate the ID, and either reuse it in both dispatched actions, or even grab the newly created entry using `getState` after the first action is dispatched.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148543/discussion-between-malo-guertin-and-markerikson).

Comment: Afraid I don't have time to discuss this further at the moment.  But, I'll be online in the Reactiflux chat channels this evening as usual.  Please feel free to ping me there or ask others as well.  Invite link is at https://www.reactiflux.com .

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly valid. This pattern even has a name. "Applying a change set"

Your message becomes the following:

```
{type: APPLY_CHANGSET, data: {id: idOfThingToApplyTo, propOne: '1', propTwo: '2'}}
```

Your reducers can then look like this:

```
const propOneReducer = (value = 'default', {type, {data: {propOne}}) => {
  return type === APPLY_CHANGSET && propOne !== undefined ? propOne : value;
}
```

This makes it a lot easier to add new properties (attributes) to your objects in your store. Adding a reducer, and sending the data from your react views to the actionCreator. In simple cases, you might not even need to change the actionCreator.

In these simple cases you can even build a reducer creator, basically creating the reducer for you.

Pro's

- Less actions in the system
- Simple sweet actionCreators

Not Pro's

- Actions don't describe exactly what is happening. It's also harder to parse exactly what happens to the store after a actionCreator is invoked. This because the reducers now take the shape of the data into account.
- Slightly more complex reducers